# Chart.js fix minimum axes?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

This is my chart:

[image]

I'm reading the documentation looking for some explanation of how to set an' minimum axe for my chart. I wanted to start at 0, instead of 2000.

How can I do that?

This is my code:

```
var dataBar = {
        labels: [dataChart[0]['mesReferencia'],dataChart[1]['mesReferencia'],dataChart[2]['mesReferencia']], 
        datasets: [{
            label: "CPF's Enviados", 
            backgroundColor: "rgba(0,51,90,0.8)",
            borderColor: "rgba(0,51,90,0.9)",
            borderWidth: 2,
            hoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(0,51,90,0.9)",
            hoverBorderColor: "rgba(0,51,90,1)",
            data: [dataChart[0]['cpfsEnviados'],dataChart[1]['cpfsEnviados'],dataChart[2]['cpfsEnviados']]
        },
        {
            label: "Propostas Finalizadas",
            backgroundColor: "rgba(0,130,229,0.8)",
            borderColor: "rgba(0,130,229,0.9)",
            borderWidth: 2,
            hoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(0,130,229,0.9)",
            hoverBorderColor: "rgba(0,130,229,1)",
            data: [dataChart[0]['propostasFinalizadas'],dataChart[1]['propostasFinalizadas'],dataChart[2]['propostasFinalizadas']]
        },
        {
            label: "Propostas Aprovadas", 
            backgroundColor: "rgba(43,139,74,0.8)", 
            borderColor: "rgba(43,139,74,0.9)", 
            borderWidth: 2, 
            hoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(43,139,74,0.9)", 
            hoverBorderColor: "rgba(43,139,74,1)", 
            data: [dataChart[0]['propostasAprovadas'],dataChart[1]['propostasAprovadas'],dataChart[2]['propostasAprovadas']]
        }]
    };
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set beginAtZero: true for ticks in your options. Here is an example:

`var options = {
      type: 'bar',
      responsive: true,
      legend: false,
      animation: false,
      scales: {
        xAxes: [{
            display: true,
            gridLines: {
                display: false
            },
        }],
        yAxes: [{
            display: true,
            gridLines: {
                display: false
            },
            ticks: {
                 beginAtZero:true
            }
        }]
      }
    };`

Comment: I'm glad I could help.